# XSLT required to format a table of contents in an XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to style sheets and need a XSLT to format a table of contents in an XML file.

My input XML looks like this:

```
<tocheader>CONTENTS</tocheader>
<toccrossheading>Section 1</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>1Paragraph 1</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading>Section 2</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>2Paragraph 2</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading>Section 3</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>3Paragraph 3</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>4Paragraph 4</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading>Section 4</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>5Paragraph 5</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>6Paragraph 6</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading>Section 5</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>7Paragraph 7</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading>Agricultural enforcement officers</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>8Paragraph 8</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>9Paragraph 9</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading>Section 6</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>10Paragraph 10</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>11Paragraph 11</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>12Paragraph 12</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>13Paragraph 13</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>14Paragraph 14</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading></toccrossheading>
```

I would like output XML to look like this:

```
<ToC>
<TocTitle>CONTENTS</TocTitle>
<ToCsection>
<ToCsectionTitle>Section 1</ToCsectionTitle>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>1</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 1</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
</ToCsection>
<ToCsection>
<ToCsectionTitle>Section 2</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>2</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 2</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
</ToCsection>
<ToCsection>
<ToCsectionTitle>Section 3</ToCsectionTitle>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>3</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 3</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>4</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 4</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
</ToCsection>
<ToCsection>
<ToCsectionTitle>Section 4</ToCsectionTitle>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>5</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 5</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>6</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 6</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
</ToCsection>
<ToCsection>
<ToCsectionTitle>Section 5</ToCsectionTitle>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>7</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 7</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
</ToCsection>
<ToCsection>
<ToCsectionTitle>Agricultural enforcement officers</ToCsectionTitle>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>8</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 8</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>9</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 9</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
</ToCsection>
<ToCsection>
<ToCsectionTitle>Section 6</ToCsectionTitle>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>10</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 10</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>11</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 11</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>12</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 12</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>13</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 13</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>14</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Paragraph 14</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
</ToCsection>
</ToC>
```

I have been playing with the XSLT code below but not having any success:

```
<xsl:template match="ToC">
<ToC>
<TocTitle><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/></TocTitle>
</ToC>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: input xml is invalid as there is no root you need an element in which to encapsulate the others

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've been reading through http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_intro.asp in which the examples use xsl:stylesheet version="1.0". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main pieces to getting the output you're requesting:

1. Grouping based on the `toccrossheading`
2. String manipulation to separate the `tocsectionnumber`

Both grouping and string manipulation are a lot easier in XSLT 2.0.

Grouping in 1.0 is normally done using [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) using `xsl:key`. In my example I did not use muenchian grouping. Instead I compared generated id's. I thought that this would be easier to understand, but I could be wrong. Besides, I'm not very good at muenchian grouping as I primarily use XSLT 2.0 and it has different/easier (my opinion) ways of grouping. You can still use muenchian grouping in 2.0 though.

Basic string manipulation in 1.0 is normally done with `substring()`, `substring-before()`, and `substring-after()`. If it's at all complicated, recursive templates can be used. My example below is pretty fragile becaue the `tocsectionnumber` must always have the text `Paragraph` in it.

Anyway, here's an example of one way you could write this transform...

**XML Input** (added root element to make well-formed)

```
<toc>
    <tocheader>CONTENTS</tocheader>
    <toccrossheading>Section 1</toccrossheading>
    <tocsectionnumber>1Paragraph 1</tocsectionnumber>
    <toccrossheading>Section 2</toccrossheading>
    <tocsectionnumber>2Paragraph 2</tocsectionnumber>
    <toccrossheading>Section 3</toccrossheading>
    <tocsectionnumber>3Paragraph 3</tocsectionnumber>
    <tocsectionnumber>4Paragraph 4</tocsectionnumber>
    <toccrossheading>Section 4</toccrossheading>
    <tocsectionnumber>5Paragraph 5</tocsectionnumber>
    <tocsectionnumber>6Paragraph 6</tocsectionnumber>
    <toccrossheading>Section 5</toccrossheading>
    <tocsectionnumber>7Paragraph 7</tocsectionnumber>
    <toccrossheading>Agricultural enforcement officers</toccrossheading>
    <tocsectionnumber>8Paragraph 8</tocsectionnumber>
    <tocsectionnumber>9Paragraph 9</tocsectionnumber>
    <toccrossheading>Section 6</toccrossheading>
    <tocsectionnumber>10Paragraph 10</tocsectionnumber>
    <tocsectionnumber>11Paragraph 11</tocsectionnumber>
    <tocsectionnumber>12Paragraph 12</tocsectionnumber>
    <tocsectionnumber>13Paragraph 13</tocsectionnumber>
    <tocsectionnumber>14Paragraph 14</tocsectionnumber>
    <toccrossheading></toccrossheading>
</toc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <ToC>
            <TocTitle><xsl:apply-templates select="tocheader"/></TocTitle>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="toccrossheading[string()]">
                <!--I use [string()] here to skip the empty toccrossheading
                in the sample input.-->
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ToC>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="toccrossheading">
        <ToCsection>
            <ToCsectionTitle>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </ToCsectionTitle>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::tocsectionnumber[generate-id(current())=generate-id(preceding-sibling::toccrossheading[1])]">
                <!--This is the only slightly tricky part of
                the stylesheet. This is where I'm comparing
                generated id's of the current toccrossheading
                and the first preceding sibling toccrossheading 
                of the following sibling tocsectionnumber's.-->
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ToCsection>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tocsectionnumber">
        <TocItem>
            <TocItemNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'Paragraph')"/>
            </TocItemNumber>
            <TocItemTitle>
                <xsl:text>Paragraph</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'Paragraph')"/>
            </TocItemTitle>
        </TocItem>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<ToC>
   <TocTitle>CONTENTS</TocTitle>
   <ToCsection>
      <ToCsectionTitle>Section 1</ToCsectionTitle>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>1</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 1</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
   </ToCsection>
   <ToCsection>
      <ToCsectionTitle>Section 2</ToCsectionTitle>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>2</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 2</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
   </ToCsection>
   <ToCsection>
      <ToCsectionTitle>Section 3</ToCsectionTitle>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>3</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 3</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>4</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 4</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
   </ToCsection>
   <ToCsection>
      <ToCsectionTitle>Section 4</ToCsectionTitle>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>5</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 5</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>6</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 6</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
   </ToCsection>
   <ToCsection>
      <ToCsectionTitle>Section 5</ToCsectionTitle>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>7</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 7</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
   </ToCsection>
   <ToCsection>
      <ToCsectionTitle>Agricultural enforcement officers</ToCsectionTitle>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>8</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 8</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>9</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 9</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
   </ToCsection>
   <ToCsection>
      <ToCsectionTitle>Section 6</ToCsectionTitle>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>10</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 10</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>11</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 11</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>12</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 12</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>13</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 13</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
      <TocItem>
         <TocItemNumber>14</TocItemNumber>
         <TocItemTitle>Paragraph 14</TocItemTitle>
      </TocItem>
   </ToCsection>
</ToC>
```

Answer (score 0):

your input requires a root element e.g

```
<root>
<tocheader>CONTENTS</tocheader>
<toccrossheading>Section 1</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>1Paragraph 1</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading>Section 2</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>2Paragraph 2</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading>Section 3</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>3Paragraph 3</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>4Paragraph 4</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading>Section 4</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>5Paragraph 5</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>6Paragraph 6</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading>Section 5</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>7Paragraph 7</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading>Agricultural enforcement officers</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>8Paragraph 8</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>9Paragraph 9</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading>Section 6</toccrossheading>
<tocsectionnumber>10Paragraph 10</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>11Paragraph 11</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>12Paragraph 12</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>13Paragraph 13</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>14Paragraph 14</tocsectionnumber>
<toccrossheading></toccrossheading>
</root>
```

you can then make a hit vs root with template like this

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <ToC>
        <TocTitle><xsl:value-of select="tocheader"/></TocTitle>
    </ToC>
</xsl:template>
```

match / will mean the root scope so you can then select or match templates against elements within this scope or traverse.... whatever!

Comment: That still won't work. Your match would have to be `/*` (or `/root` or change the `select`).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. How to I code for 1-2 digits for the paragraph numbers?